# File Replication Service Errors

Tags: windows-server-2003, replication

We have a windows 2003 r2 server and couple of the users are reporting that they can not scan files into the windwos server. They are getting an Out of Space errors. I took a look at the server and we have 600GB free disk space on that partition. But while looking at the event log I found a lot of errors like (13552,13555)

```
The File Replication Service is unable to add this computer to the following replica set: 
    "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)" 

This could be caused by a number of problems such as: 
  --  an invalid root path, 
  --  a missing directory, 
  --  a missing disk volume, 
  --  a file system on the volume that does not support NTFS 5.0 

The information below may help to resolve the problem: 
Computer DNS name is "server.domain.local" 
Replica set member name is "server" 
Replica set root path is "c:\windows\sysvol\domain" 
Replica staging directory path is "c:\windows\sysvol\staging\domain" 
Replica working directory path is "c:\windows\ntfrs\jet" 
Windows error status code is  
FRS error status code is FrsErrorMismatchedJournalId 

Other event log messages may also help determine the problem.  Correct the problem and the service will attempt to restart replication automatically at a later time.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the line `FRS error status code is FrsErrorMismatchedJournalID`. You've got a mismatched USN in the NTFS change journal and NTFRS JET database. Microsoft's [recommended workaround procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925633) is to set a registry value ("BurFlags") and bounce the NTFRS service.